# Left-align a TextView to the text inside an EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment

I'd like to align the text in a `TextView` with text inside an `EditText` that is directly below it.  Is this possible without using padding tricks?

If not, is this because it's discouraged?  I could see it being discouraged because it could confuse the user into missing the distinction between the two controls.

[image]

Here's the layout that created the above screenshot:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Please align my first character" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view"
        android:hint="To my first character" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this without using padding or `layout_margin`. `EditText` has a background with borders and padding, so its content area is a little bit smaller than the area of `TextView`. I think it's normal to use padding in such situations.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this can be confusing, but you can add a little offset to the `TextView` to make it look better. Use `android:layout_marginLeft` and choose a value that will match your requirements. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you will have to use padding to the `TextView`. It actually looks better to me that the first character in `TextView` and that in `EditView` are NOT aligned perfectly. They also have different font size, so it actually looks pretty natural the way it is right now - or maybe with just a little bit of padding, but not too much. When padding, don't forget to consider users with different screen sizes and resolutions, so please use `dp` with you are doing padding with `android:layout_marginLeft`. For example:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="Please align my first character" />
```

Hope this helps.